# После запуска программы с dll-библиотеками выдает: "В GDI+ возникла ошибка общего вида." C#

Tags: c#, winforms, dllimport

Запускаю программу, включаю функцию, все считается, но спустя 5 секунд выдает ошибку "В GDI+ возникла ошибка общего вида."
Вот код:

```
using System;

namespace dll_usage_demo
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "LoadLibrary")]
        static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string lpLibFileName);
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetProcAddress")]
        static extern IntPtr GetProcAddress(IntPtr hModule, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string lpProcName);
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "FreeLibrary")]
        static extern bool FreeLibrary(IntPtr hModule);
        [DllImport("Kernel32.dll")]
        private static extern bool QueryPerformanceCounter(
           out long lpPerformanceCount);
        [DllImport("Kernel32.dll")]
        private static extern bool QueryPerformanceFrequency(
            out long lpFrequency);
        [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        delegate int FmasProc_v3(double[] mas1, int size1, double[] mas2, int size2);
        [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        delegate int FmasProc_v4(double[] mas1, int size1, double[] mas2, int size2);
        [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        delegate int Fmas2Proc(IntPtr[] mas1, int h, int w);

        private long FBeginCount, FEndCount;
        private long FFrequence;
        Double Ftime;

        public int sizetimes = 50;
        public double[] mas1;
        public double[] mas2;
        public double[][] masX;
        public double[][] masX1;
        public int Hs = 700, Ws = 700, size = 100000;

        void fillArray1d(double[] arr, int size){
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
                arr[i] = (double)((i * i + 10) / (i + i + 1));
            }
        }
        void fillArray2d(double[][] arr, int height, int width){
            for (int i = 0; i < height; i++){
                for (int j = 0; j < width; j++){
                    arr[i][j] = (double)((i * j + 10) / (i + j + 1));
                }
            }
        }

        string[] func_name1 = { "alg1", "alg2", "alg3" };
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

             mas1 = new double[size];
             mas2 = new double[size];

            fillArray1d(mas1, size);
            fillArray1d(mas2 , size);


            masX = new double[Hs][];
            for (int y = 0; y < Hs; y++)
            {
                masX[y] = new double[Ws];
            }
            fillArray2d(masX, Hs, Ws);
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Dll_demo_work_cdecl("cpplib.dll", func_name1);
        }
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Dll_demo_work_cdecl("delphilib.dll", func_name1);
        }
        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Dll_demo_work_cdecl("cppblib.dll", func_name1);
        }

        void show_min_max_avg(double [] times, int sizetimes)
        {
            double min = times[0];
            double max = times[0];
            double avg = 0.0;
            
            for (int i = 0; i < sizetimes; i++)
            {
                avg += times[i];
                if (min > times[i]) min = times[i];
                if (max < times[i]) max = times[i];
            }
            avg /= 50.0;

            richTextBox1.AppendText("Min: " + min.ToString() + '\n');
            richTextBox1.AppendText("Max: " + max.ToString() + '\n');
            richTextBox1.AppendText("Avg: " + avg.ToString() + '\n'+'\n');

        }

        void Dll_demo_work_cdecl(string dll_name, string[] func_name)
        {
            double[] m1 = new double[size];
            double[] m2 = new double[size];
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                m1[i] = 2 * i * Math.Pow((-1), i);
                m2[i] = i;
            }

            int sizetimes = 50;
            double [] times = new double[50];
            IntPtr pProc;
            richTextBox1.Clear();

            IntPtr pDll = LoadLibrary(dll_name);
            if (pDll == IntPtr.Zero){
                richTextBox1.AppendText("ERROR: unable to load DLL:  " + dll_name);
                return;
            }// Проверка на подключение dll
            richTextBox1.AppendText("func (" + dll_name + ") Loaded \n");

            pProc = GetProcAddress(pDll, func_name[0]);
            if (pProc == IntPtr.Zero){
                richTextBox1.AppendText("\nERROR: unable to find DLL function (" + func_name[0] + ")");
            }// Проверка на присутсвие функции
            else{
                richTextBox1.AppendText("func (" + func_name[0] + ") Loaded \n");
                FmasProc_v3 sub_arrays = (FmasProc_v3)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(pProc, typeof(FmasProc_v3));
                    for (int w = 0; w < sizetimes; w++){
                        QueryPerformanceFrequency(out FFrequence);
                        QueryPerformanceCounter(out FBeginCount);
                        int pRes = sub_arrays(mas1, size, mas2, size);                        
                        QueryPerformanceCounter(out FEndCount);
                        Ftime = ((FEndCount - FBeginCount) / (double)FFrequence) * 1000;
                        times[w] = Ftime;
                    }
                show_min_max_avg(times, sizetimes);
            }

            pProc = GetProcAddress(pDll, func_name[1]);
            if (pProc == IntPtr.Zero){
                richTextBox1.AppendText("\nERROR: unable to find DLL function (" + func_name[1] + ")");
            }// Проверка на присутсвие функции
            else{
                richTextBox1.AppendText("func (" + func_name[1] + ") Loaded \n");
                FmasProc_v4 find_max_neg_num = (FmasProc_v4)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(pProc, typeof(FmasProc_v4));
                for (int w = 0; w < sizetimes; w++){
                        QueryPerformanceFrequency(out FFrequence);
                        QueryPerformanceCounter(out FBeginCount);
                        int pRes = find_max_neg_num(mas1, size, mas2, size);
                        QueryPerformanceCounter(out FEndCount);
                        Ftime = ((FEndCount - FBeginCount) / (double)FFrequence) * 1000;
                        times[w] = Ftime;
                    }
                show_min_max_avg(times, sizetimes);
            }            

            int testst;
            pProc = GetProcAddress(pDll, func_name[2]);
            if (pProc == IntPtr.Zero){
                richTextBox1.AppendText("\nERROR: unable to find DLL function (" + func_name[2] + ")");
            }// Проверка на присутсвие функции
            else{
                richTextBox1.AppendText("library (" + func_name[2] + ") Loaded \n");
                Fmas2Proc find_intersections_q = (Fmas2Proc)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(pProc, typeof(Fmas2Proc));
                unsafe{
                    IntPtr[] mas_ptrs1 = new IntPtr[Hs];
                    for (int i = 0; i < Hs; i++){
                        fixed (void* ptr = masX[i]){
                            mas_ptrs1[i] = new IntPtr(ptr);
                        }
                    }

                    for (int w = 0; w < sizetimes; w++){
                        QueryPerformanceFrequency(out FFrequence);
                        QueryPerformanceCounter(out FBeginCount);
                        testst = find_intersections_q(mas_ptrs1, Hs, Ws);
                        QueryPerformanceCounter(out FEndCount);
                        Ftime = ((FEndCount - FBeginCount) / (double)FFrequence) * 1000;
                        times[w] = Ftime;
                    }
                }
                show_min_max_avg(times, sizetimes);   
            }
            FreeLibrary(pDll);
        }

    }
}
```

При отладки данной ошибки не поялвяется, только в релизе

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException
  HResult=0x80004005
  Сообщение = В GDI+ возникла ошибка общего вида.
  Источник = System.Drawing
  Трассировка стека:
   at System.Drawing.Graphics.get_Clip()
   at System.Drawing.GraphicsContext..ctor(Graphics g)
   at System.Drawing.Graphics.Save()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmPaint(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

Comment: в этом коде не используется GDI+ вообще, либо я этого не вижу. При каких условиях возникает исключение? Нужно больше подробностей. Отредактируйте вопрос, добавьте больше информации об отладке.

Comment: Начните с того что надо убрать весь свой код из конструктора формы и переместить его в обработчик `Form.Load`. Щелкните в дизайнере двойным кликом по пустому месту, чтобы он появился. В конструкторе формы оставьте только `InitializeComponent()`. Кстати, это может помочь исправить проблему.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема оказалось в том что у меня DLL библиотеки с функциями double, а здесь я их записываю как int